# How to pass a variable from a cs file to a cshtml file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC application.
I would like to pass a variable, which is a list, from a cs file, my HomeController.cs file, to a cshtml file, Report.cshtml (so I can use it in a script).

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pass it in a model or viewbag, viewdata, tempdata, make an ajax request to the controller depending on your requirements - there are many ways to get the data...

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. My variable is a database stored locally, which is a List<Dashboard___Veins_Data___By_Institution> type.  What do you think is the best solution for that?

Comment: The question starts off on the wrong foot by considering "files" to be the actors in the application's runtime. This suggests an issue with the basic understanding of how the code translates into the runtime behavior; which makes it difficult to provide a meaningful answer here. It would be more productive to follow a more guided tutorial on the basics of MVC as this will teach you the necessary skills, as well as providing the solution for the current problem. If you try to force a solution without really understanding what's going on, you will struggle greatly.

Comment: There isn't enough details - this is a decision you need to make depending on your design and requirements. If you're not familiar with any of the above, then I'd recommend you look them up and make a decision based on that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will look that.

Comment: Hi again, I tried to use ViewBag and ViewData, but it's not working in my JS script. 
In my Controller I have "ViewBag.Message = my_list;" and in my View, I have "var data = @(ViewBag.Message);".
Is it working only if we use it inside the html with the razor markup? Or is it possible to use it in a JS script? Thanks

Comment: Anyone got an idea?